# How to optimize a row transfer between two identical tables

Tags: performance, insert

I would like to find an approach to improve the performance of a nightly query on my database. It currently takes about 15 minutes and places some locks, degrading the overall application performance. My goal is simple. I have 2 tables, A and B, with exactly the same columns, including a column MyDate (datetime). Throughout the day, 24/7, there are constant insertions into table A (no deletes or updates) with MyDate = getDate().

Every night, I want to move all rows from table A where MyDate < getDate() to empty table A and fill table B. During the transfer, there are ongoing insertions into table A, which will be moved the following night.

In summary, I've done the following:

```
-- Executed at midnight
DECLARE @myDate datetime;
SELECT @myDate = GETDATE();
INSERT INTO B SELECT * FROM A WHERE MyDate < @myDate;
DELETE FROM A WHERE MyDate < @myDate;
```

What approach do you suggest to improve performance and avoid locking table A during the row transfer between the two tables? I have approximately 1 million rows inserted into table A daily, resulting in around 3 to 5 GB of data.

I don't really have any other ideas to improve performance and am actively looking for suggestions, perhaps involving loops and cursors, I'm not sure